# Getting street name from Address/Location object in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

I'm trying to get the street name of my current location but I can't seem to get it.

I use this method to retrieve the Address:

```
public Address getAddressForLocation(Context context, Location location) throws IOException {

        if (location == null) {
            return null;
        }
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        int maxResults = 1;

        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, maxResults);

        if (addresses.size() == 1) {
            return addresses.get(0);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And then I can do things like. `address.getLocality()` and `address.getPostalCode()`

But what I want is the street name. Like in "Potterstreet 12". When I print the AddressLine(0) and AddressLine(1) I only get the postalcode, city and country.

How can I retrieve the street name of the position i'm currently at?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried using `getAddressLine` ? 
See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html#getAddressLine%28int%29) for more info on this method

Something like this should do (untested):

```
for (int i = 0; i < addresses.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
 Log.d("=Adress=",addresses.getAddressLine(i));
}
```

Comment: Yeah, like I said above, when I print getAddressLine(0) and (1) i get the postalcode, city and country. No street name..

Comment: Sorry, I havent noticed it. Maybe you can try sending via the emulator some latitude and longitude of another location and check if you can see some street names returned.

Comment: Maybe you could also increase the maxResult to check what the other results contain as info.

Comment: I already increased maxResult and it didn't work..
I think that it indeed lays on the fact that I my location just doesn't have an address. I'm developping on a phone btw.
The emulator is really bad if you want to test location-based apps.

Comment: On my HTC Desire, under Applications -> Development, I have an option called 'Allow mock locations'. Maybe you can activate this and send the geolocation from DDMS to the phone (I have never tried it though)

Comment: I hardcoded a diffrent location in my app. It was a random American location (39.753696, -105.062706)

Here I got the address with address.getAddresLine(0) It also had 3 MaxAddresLine's while my own (dutch) location has only 2.
I guess Maps doesn't support my location..

Comment: This is the problem I'm having...looking for an efficient way to get the country name when the address objects don't always have the same number of address lines.

Answer (score 9):

Try something like this in your code

```
String cityName=null;              
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(),Locale.getDefault());               
List<Address>  addresses;    
try {    
   addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location  
                   .getLongitude(), 1);    
   if (addresses.size() > 0) 
        StreetName=addresses.get(0).getThoroughfare();
        String s = longitude+"\n"+latitude +  
        "\n\nMy Currrent Street is: "+StreetName; 
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

it works for me :-) Good luck ;-)

Comment: getThoroughfare() returns null in cases when you are in suburban area. It can't be generalized to every location of the user.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a complete address (city + street), in

```
address.getAddressLine(0)
```

you find the street name and number.

Answer (score 1):

getFromLocation wasn't working for me either. There are a couple steps you can take. 
1. First off go into gradle and make sure you are using the latest play services lib.
2. Don't over specify, the reason I got no results is because I had to much info in my address. When I removed the postal code I got results every time.
3. Try the online api:
 http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=192%20McEwan%20Dr%20E,%20Caledon,%20ON&sensor=false
Just replace the address in there with yours.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem but with the Country name, this is the function I ended up using:

```
function getCountry(results) {
    var geocoderAddressComponent,addressComponentTypes,address;
    for (var i in results) {
      geocoderAddressComponent = results[i].address_components;
      for (var j in geocoderAddressComponent) {
        address = geocoderAddressComponent[j];
        addressComponentTypes = geocoderAddressComponent[j].types;
        for (var k in addressComponentTypes) {
          if (addressComponentTypes[k] == 'country') {
            return address.long_name;
          }
        }
      }
    }
   return 'Unknown';
 }
```

You should be able to adapt this to get the street name out without much fuss.

[Inspired by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602822/how-can-i-get-google-maps-location-names)

Answer (score -3):

```
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = 
                gcd.getFromLocation(currentLatitude, currentLongitude,100);
if (addresses.size() > 0 && addresses != null) {
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                myaddress.setText(addresses.get(0).getFeatureName()+"-"+addresses.get(0).getLocality()+"-"+addresses.get(0).getAdminArea()+"-"+addresses.get(0).getCountryName());
}
```

- getfeaturename() return Streetname
- getlocality() return city
- getadminarea() return State

That's All..!