# How can I get google maps location names?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I'm building a site in which it is required to get all google maps locations, from countries names to the smallest village. Is this anywhere in the api? Because it is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a way to scrape all of Google's data, that would be against the [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos).  If you just need to find a location name for a few geographic points, that would be an application of the [reverse geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding).

Comment: Thanx for the quick answer. I'm looking specifically for getting countries and cities from google api as string. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Based on what information?  A latitude/longitude coordinate? A viewport/bounds?

Comment: This is a good question. I'm sad it got downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the response to get that data out, so for example if you want to get the country and results is the result object you get by calling the reverse Gecoding:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding

Then the function for getting the country would be:

```
       function getCountry(results) {
         var geocoderAddressComponent,addressComponentTypes,address;
         for (var i in results) {
           geocoderAddressComponent = results[i].address_components;
           for (var j in geocoderAddressComponent) {
             address = geocoderAddressComponent[j];
             addressComponentTypes = geocoderAddressComponent[j].types;
             for (var k in addressComponentTypes) {
               if (addressComponentTypes[k] == 'country') {
                 return address;
               }
             }
           }
         }
        return 'Unknown';
      }
```

Comment: With a small amount of tweaking this did exactly the job I wanted! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you need the "name" associated with a place on a Google Maps API v3 map based on its geographic coordinates (latitude and longitude), use the [reverse geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding), it returns many levels of information for that location.

[Example from the documentation](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse)

Note, that except for the fact that it won't necessarily correlate with the Google Maps API v3 tiles, [geonames.org](http://www.geonames.org/) might have the information you need or a less restrictive service to get it.